# Rangy applyToSelection at the cursor if the selected range is empty?

Tags: javascript, rangy

This feels like a stupid question.

I'm using the excellent Rangy library in javascript to apply CSS classes from a dropdown to selected text, as if in a rich text editor.

But if the user is simply typing text without making a selection, and they apply a class via a dropdown, rangy's "applyToSelection" does nothing since,presumably, it's an empty range.

I know there are difficult ways to add a proper div at the selected cursor location and enter into it, but, before I embark on those, am I missing a simple way to do it, either using Rangy or normal JS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I ended up with, which worked perfectly in IE11 but has not been tested in other browsers yet:

```
        var actual_textarea = document.getElementById("my_input_textarea");
        actual_textarea.focus();
        var selectedInstance = this.ne.selectedInstance;
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        var new_div = document.createElement("div");
        new_div.innerHTML = "<div class='" + this.rangyClassPrefix + elm + "'></div>";
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        var node, lastNode;
        while (node = new_div.firstChild)
        {
            lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
        }   
        range.insertNode(frag);
        if (lastNode)
        {
            range = range.cloneRange();

            range.selectNodeContents(lastNode);
            range.collapse(false);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
```

Notice that I set focus first since the style is being applied by focus-changing clicks on other elements.

I'm still a little fuzzy at the thought of range clones being value rather than reference clones but still working perfectly when added, since that's counterintuitive, but it does work.

Thanks!